# New Alfresco version install - missing folders

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm a newbie in Alfresco, but my collegue worked with that.
He prepared a workflow in our old Alfresco server (4.2.b)
I currently have installed Alfresco 5.0.a in a new server. He left me a how-to guide to deploy the workflow in the new server.

The problem is that I can't find the workflow folder under

***/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/workflow***

Is there a new folder where I should deploy my workflow?
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Best regards

Mattia Parise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you are missing is in `alfresco-repository-5.0.a.jar`. Although bad practice, just creating the folder and dropping your files there should work fine. I am fairly sure using `/opt/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/workflow` works as well. I would try the latter  first.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not try with the shared folder , but with the web-inf one. I tried,  I deployed the workflow as my collegue said  but no success. I will try with the repository suggestion and then check if there could be a problem with the workflow models and with the other files. Thanks for your aswer!

Comment: Just dropping the files in the workflow folder won't make the system pick them up. You definitely have to wire them in a spring context.

Comment: You mean deploying then the workflow with Explorer?
I found the file alfresco-repository-5.0.a.jar  in /opt/alfresco-5.0.a/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib.
I don't know how to use it, can you please give me some info about that?

Comment: Don't mess  with that jar file. Try putting the things in shared/classes/alfresco. Have a look at http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/tasks/kb-code-workflow.html. Look for parallel.workflowBootstrap to see an example - that's most likely what you want.